# Problema al poblar Recyclerview desde Firebase Database en Android

Tags: android, firebase, recyclerview

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema al poblar recyclerview con datos desde Firebase database.

Estos son los datos que tengo guardado en la base de datos de Firebase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todos tienen las mismas características(descripción, imagen, precio, tipo).

Mi problema es al querer poblar **TODOS LOS DATOS EXISTENTES**(**desde Lápidas hasta Tazas**) en el RecyclerView, no me muestra nada, no tengo error en el RecyclerView personalizado ni nada, ya que al poblar con los datos de, por ejemplo "lozas", este me funciona perfectamente, dejo acá el codigo donde se llena el recyclerview. Probablemente acá estoy haciendo algo mal.

```
public class ProductosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private RecyclerView recyclerProductos;   
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference data;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_productos);

    recyclerProductos = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerProductos);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerProductos.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando imagenes..");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    data = firebaseDatabase.getReference("productos");
    data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<ProductoBean> pb = new ArrayList<ProductoBean>();
                             pb.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot dt : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ProductoBean prod = dt.getValue(ProductoBean.class);
                Log.i("Datos", dt.getValue().toString());
                pb.add(prod);
            }

            ProductoAdaptador adaptador = new ProductoAdaptador(ProductosActivity.this, pb);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            recyclerProductos.setAdapter(adaptador);

            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("Error", databaseError.getMessage());
           }
       });
     }
  }
```

Cuando quiero poblar solamente datos de por ejemplo "lozas", hago esto y me funciona correctamente.

```
                         .
                         .
                         .

  data.child("lozas")addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<ProductoBean> pb = new ArrayList<ProductoBean>();
                             pb.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot dt : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ProductoBean prod = dt.getValue(ProductoBean.class);
                Log.i("Datos", dt.getValue().toString());
                pb.add(prod);
            }

            ProductoAdaptador adaptador = new ProductoAdaptador(ProductosActivity.this, pb);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            recyclerProductos.setAdapter(adaptador);

            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("Error", databaseError.getMessage());
           }
       });
     }
  }
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
Este código es del Adaptador del recyclerview.

```
public class ProductoAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductoAdaptador.ProductoViewHolder> {

ArrayList<ProductoBean> productoBean;
Context context;


public ProductoAdaptador(Context ctx, ArrayList<ProductoBean> pb){
    this.context = ctx;
    this.productoBean = pb;
}


@Override
public ProductoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recyclerview_productos,parent,false);
    ProductoViewHolder holder = new ProductoViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductoViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ProductoBean prod = productoBean.get(position);

    Picasso.with(context).load(prod.getImagen()).into(holder.imagen);
    //holder.imagen.setImageUrl(prod.getImagen());
    holder.tipo.setText(prod.getTipo());
    holder.descripcion.setText(prod.getDescripcion());
    holder.precio.setText(prod.getPrecio());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productoBean.size();
}

public static class ProductoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    SmartImageView imagen;
    AutofitTextView tipo, descripcion, precio;


    public ProductoViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imagen = (SmartImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.SmartImageProducto);
        tipo = (AutofitTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTipoProducto);
        descripcion = (AutofitTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcionProducto);
        precio = (AutofitTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecioProducto);

         }
     }
 }
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2**

Clase ProductoBean (get/set/constructor)

```
public class ProductoBean {


private String descripcion;
private String imagen;
private String precio;
private String tipo;


public ProductoBean(){

}

public ProductoBean(String descripcion, String imagen, String precio, String tipo){
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.imagen = imagen;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.tipo = tipo;
}


public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getImagen() {
    return imagen;
}

public void setImagen(String imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}

public String getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(String precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
```

}

**Entonces finalmente mi consulta es cómo hacer para poblar el recycler con todos los datos(desde lapidas hasta tazas).**

Comment: Si un `RecyclerView` no te muestra nada, probablemente es un problema del `Adapter` o del `ViewHolder`. Podrías compartir como implementaste estos dos? Supongo que tu `Adapter` es `ProductoAdapter`.

Comment: @StefanNolde pero como dije arriba, cuando hago el código para mostrar datos de algo en especifico, como por ejemplo "lozas" me lo muestra perfectamente. Está bien, ahorita edito mi publicación para mostrar el adaptador.

Comment: En tu log (`Log.i("Datos", dt.getValue().toString());`) se ve que tu arreglo se esta llenando?

Comment: @StefanNolde Había olvidado eso; cuando hago para q me aparezcan los datos de cierta parte me aparecen los datos respectivos que está agarrando del Firebase, ahí todo bien; el problema surge a la hora de capturar los datos de todo, en mi log me aparecen los datos pero en el RUN salen ciertas cosas como: `No setter/field for lapida2 found on class com.example.jorge.fotoceramica.bean.ProductoBean` y 5 lineas más de lo mismo, por lo que he leído es porque algo está mal escrito en la clase de los métodos get/set; pero ya me fijé en eso, actualizaré el post poniendo la clase ProductoBean